# display variable image using cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, image

I want to display an image on a web page based on a certain cookie value that is passed/created up clicking through to this page. I was thinking about writing the cookie with a onClick action thinking that this would be easiest but I'm still open to ideas. Here is a sample of that link.

a href="myLink.html" onClick="setCookie(BRAND,ABC,3600);return true;">

Below is some code I have lifted from the net that mimics what I'm looking for in a basic way. I just dont know how to make the js call on the page get the cookie value and set the image.

I appreciate the help in advance and thank you for reading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var picData = [
        ['ABC','ABC.jpg'],
        ['DEF','DEF.jpg'],
        ['GHI','GHI.jpg']
    ];
    window.onload=function(){
        var cookieValue = 'ABC';  //substitute your code to get the cookie value for this line
        for(i=0; i < picData.length; i++){
            if(cookieValue == picData[i][0]) {
               document.getElementById('imgCont').src = picData[i][1];
               i=picData.length;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <img id="imgCont" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: A good resource: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using PHP instead? I feel that it would be a lot more straightfoward. Use [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and then simple if and elseif statements to check what the cookie is, and display a corresponding image.

This seems a lot simpler than what you're trying to do with JavaScript, but maybe that's just because I use PHP so much more often...

So maybe something like

```
$value = "something"; /* sets the value of the cookie */
setcookie("imagedisplay", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

on the previous page, and then to check it just use:

```
if($_COOKIE["imagedisplay"] == "something") {
$imageurl="ABC.jpg";
}
elseif($_COOKIE["imagedisplay"] == "something else") {
$imageurl="DEF.jpg";
}
else {
$imageurl="GHI.jpg";
}
```

And then use some more PHP to output the corresponding URL as the source of the image. Something like

```
<img src="<? echo $imageurl; ?>" />
```

Haven't tested this code, but it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm terrible at php and wouldnt even know how to host my test site. I appreciate the reply. I can visually grasp and see how your setting the value (though I'm not sure what I would do with "something" and "something else"), I can see how your calling up later in the page. However... I just suck at php. :(

Comment: "something" and "something else" are the values for the `imagedisplay` cookie. For example, let's say there are three different pages (page1 page2 and page3) that direct to your current page. The cookie can be used like this: If the user came from page1, then set the cookie value to "1". If they came from page2, set the cookie value to "2" and so on. Then, in the PHP code with the if statements, you're checking to see what page they came from by looking at what cookie was passed. Does this make sense? BTW, you might wanna consider learning PHP, it's essential to almost all web development :P